# Python Type Annotation Understanding Problem

Tags: python, python-3.x, mypy

i have a bit of an understanding problem with python type annotations. Consider the following function that is used to convert a dict to a standardized format

```py
from __future__ import annotations  # needed for type annotations in > python 3.7
from typing import Dict, List, Union


class Producer(object):
    pass

def normalize_producers(
    producers: Dict[str, Union[Producer, List[Producer]]]
) -> Dict[str, List[Producer]]:
    """
    Function to normalize producer input to have the same format
    """
    normalized_dict: Dict[str, List[Producer]] = {}
    for key in producers.keys():
        if isinstance(producers[key], list):
            normalized_dict[key] = producers[key]
        else:
            normalized_dict[key] = [producers[key]]
    return normalized_dict
```

this example results in a type issue for the assignment of `normalized_dict`:

```
Argument of type "Producer | List[Producer]" cannot be assigned to parameter "v" of type "List[Producer]" in function "__setitem__"
  Type "Producer | List[Producer]" cannot be assigned to type "List[Producer]"
    "Producer" is incompatible with "List[Producer]"

Argument of type "list[Producer | List[Producer]]" cannot be assigned to parameter "v" of type "List[Producer]" in function "__setitem__"
  TypeVar "_T@list" is invariant
    Type "Producer | List[Producer]" cannot be assigned to type "Producer"
      "List[Producer]" is incompatible with "Producer"
```

However, when i use a temporary list, and check the type of this list, no type issues are raised:

```py
def normalize_producers_save(
    producers: Dict[str, Union[Producer, List[Producer]]]
) -> Dict[str, List[Producer]]:
    """
    Function to normalize producer input to have the same format
    """
    normalized_dict: Dict[str, List[Producer]] = {}
    for key in producers.keys():
        templist = producers[key]
        if isinstance(templist, list):
            normalized_dict[key] = templist
        else:
            normalized_dict[key] = [templist]
    return normalized_dict
```

Does this mean, that, although I assign the values of `producers` to be either of type `Producer` or `List[Producer]` `if isinstance(producers[key], list):` does not result in `producers[key]` always being of type list ? I don't understand, what the issue with the first version of the function is.

Comment: `mypy` in my experience isn't very aggresive when it comes to narrowing types. The `mypy` docs don't elaborate much on this specific case: https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/type_narrowing.html But I suspect the fact that `producers[key]` is not a simple expression makes `mypy` avoid trying to narrow the union. Just use a temp variable ... note you aren't  using a temporary list, no new objects are created when you do `templist = producers[key]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known [issue](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/7339) in the `mypy` where it does not narrow type of index expressions like `dict_var[key]`. As workaround, you can use explicit variables for dictionary values:

```
from __future__ import annotations  # needed for type annotations in > python 3.7
from typing import Dict, List, Union


class Producer(object):
    pass

def normalize_producers(
    producers: Dict[str, Union[Producer, List[Producer]]]
) -> Dict[str, List[Producer]]:
    """
    Function to normalize producer input to have the same format
    """
    normalized_dict: Dict[str, List[Producer]] = {}
    for key, value in producers.items():
        if isinstance(value, list):
            normalized_dict[key] = value
        else:
            normalized_dict[key] = [value]
    return normalized_dict
```